# How to assign ranks to records in a spark dataframe based on some conditions?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, rank

Given a dataframe :

```
+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |
+-------+-------+
|      a|      1|
+-------+-------+
|      b|      2|
+-------+-------+
|      c|      5|
+-------+-------+
|      d|      7|
+-------+-------+
|      e|     11|
+-------+-------+
```

I want to assign ranks to records based on conditions :

1. Start rank with 1
2. Assign rank = rank of previous record if ( B of current record - B of previous record ) is <= 2
3. Increment rank when ( B of current record - B of previous record ) is > 2

So I want result to be like this :

```
+-------+-------+------+
|   A   |   B   | rank |
+-------+-------+------+
|      a|      1|     1|
+-------+-------+------+
|      b|      2|     1|
+-------+-------+------+
|      c|      5|     2|
+-------+-------+------+
|      d|      7|     2|
+-------+-------+------+
|      e|     11|     3|
+-------+-------+------+
```

- Inbuilt functions in spark like rowNumber, rank, dense_rank don't
  provide any functionality to achieve this.
- I tried doing it by using a global variable rank and fetching
  previous record values using lag function but it does not give
  consistent results due to distributed processing in spark unlike in sql.
- One more method I tried was passing lag values of records to a UDF while generating a new column and applying conditions in UDF. But the problem I am facing is I can get lag values for columns A as well as B but not for column rank.
  This gives error as it cannot resolve column name rank :

  HiveContext.sql("SELECT df.*,LAG(df.rank, 1) OVER (ORDER BY B , 0) AS rank_lag, udfGetVisitNo(B,rank_lag) as rank  FROM df")
- I cannot get lag value of a column which I am currently adding.
- Also I dont want methods which require using df.collect() as this dataframe is quite large in size and collecting it on a single working node results in memory errors.

Any other method by which I can achieve the same?
I would like to know a solution having time complexity O(n) , n being the no of records.

Comment: can you sub-queries like in sql?

Comment: Yes. I can use sql like queries,  if you have a solution based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL solution would be

```
select a,b,1+sum(col) over(order by a) as rnk
from 
(
select t.*
,case when b - lag(b,1,b) over(order by a) <= 2 then 0 else 1 end as col
from t
) x
```

The solution assumes the ordering is based on column `a`.

[**`SQL Server example`**](http://rextester.com/JZW10144)

Comment: This works . Thankyou . How much will this sub-query affect the execution time of my code? I have around 7000000 records.

Comment: not sure i can guess how it affects the execution time. Try it and check. The final query is just summing up the values of the inner query.

Comment: Okay got it ! Thanks again.

Comment: @MukulChandel Subquery is not an issue here but performance wise you definitely want to avoid `over(order by a)` on any real size dataset.

Comment: Yes. I figured out this solution works in O(n^2), n being the number of records. Any other method that can achieve better time complexity?